# Configuring WCF Throttling Behaviors

Tags: wcf, throttling

which  WCF throttling setting is the best practice in case of application with large number of requests?

Comment: check this blog : http://csharp-codesamples.com/2009/04/configuring-wcf-throttling-behaviors/

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use load tests to find needed configuration. There is no magic number which will solve every situation.